# Simple way to copy files onto Windows-based Azure container instance

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-files, azcopy

Azure Files volume mounting is not supported in Windows containers.
I'm aware I can use AzCopy with Azure Files, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way that doesn't involve creating an Azure storage resource. Because I would have the added work of maintaining the creation/teardown of these storages.

Ideally, I would like the host agent (running create container), to simply copy the files directly to the container instances, therefore the files are tied to the execution of the hosting agent.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? Please let me know if you have any responses.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get back to you. Yes. This does seem to be the only way tih Azure files/AzCopy. I was just wondering of alternative solutions. I'll mark your answer as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know there is no way to copy files to the Windows-based Azure container instance except the command. The AzCopy command is OK. It's impossible that you want to do something on the host agent. You can do nothing with the ACI host agent. Additionally, the ACI is more suitable for a quick test and running of the images.

If you want to copy files and other controls on the containers, I recommend the AKS. You can run the Windows-based containers in the AKS with Windows nodes, and the Azure File volume is also available for the Windows containers. See the information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-faq#what-kind-of-disks-are-supported-for-windows).

Answer (score 0):

If your file is "quite short", you could also try this workaround:

```
$fileToCopyContent = Get-Content my_file_path
az container exec --resource-group myRg --name myCg 
   --exec-command "powershell '$fileToCopyContent' | Out-File -FilePath destination_path -Encoding UTF8"
```

Practically you create a connection with your `Windows-based Azure Docker Container` and execute a
**powershell command** used to send the content of the file.

Unfortunately the file has to be short because I've also experienced some '`The command line is too long`' exceptions.
Maybe you can try directly with the `Copy-Item` command and use UPN path. I tried and got communication issue but maybe it's just a matter of mis-configuration